# How did they get the working dream share device inside dreams in Inception?

Tags: inception

After getting into the dream they also have that dream sharing machine with them. How did they get that machine 'working' (fully functional) inside dream because inside dream that machine was just an image of the real machine.

Comment: Inception wasn't a very scientific movie, I mean a dream inside of a dream is still just a one-level dream, time isn't going to be distorted any further.  There's no great significance to the dream machines inside their dreams.  If the writers cared about details like that they couldn't have made the movie.

Comment: @Mark: Hard to make that claim until we reach the technological standpoint to actual do and measure it maybe they are using artistic license maybe they are just predicting the future. Who knows we may one learn to travel faster than light.

Comment: The machine was fully functional in the same way as all their watches, tube lights, ACs, vehicles were fully functional.

Comment: @LifeH2O, are you still looking for a more apt answer? You haven't selected any of the answers yet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's all part of the consciousness being shared by the dreamers. Basically in a dream world you can create whatever you want. Therefore, inside the many levels of dreams, they can create the dream machine being there, along with just about anything they want.
**Edit:** Because the dreamers perceive that everything occurring is real, the dream machine is then perceived to be functional causing the next level of dreaming.

Comment: In other words, when the architect designs the level, just include it in there where they can got to it.  How could it be simpler?

Answer (score 15):

The same way they got the van, the guns, and their clothes into the dream.

Wait, in this particular movie, as opposed to all the other action films, it actually makes sense that they never run out of ammo!

Comment: Upvote because I'd never thought about the unlimited ammo thing.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this is a big impossibility, not just a "litle thing with no importance". The argument of "controlling the dream towards a second and a third level" would be aceptable if a one person dream. We are talking about 7 people that share these diferent levels--too much of a distortion. The natural way to go would be each one of them walk their unique way since the second dream level. I can't accept this size of divergence.

Having said that, I close my eyes to that because I loved the movie. What I loved about the movie was the exploration of the mind features witch I think to be accurate.